# Spatie Laravel-pdf not working on server, it show command not found

Tags: laravel, spatie-browsershot

i have problem when using spatie laravel-pdf on server. it working fine on localhost, but it showing error like the text below when i upload it to server

> The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/home/u1666881/public_html/royal_ambarrukmo/api/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.cjs' '{"url":"file:///tmp/1028804210-0397463001710232070/index.html","action":"pdf","options":{"args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600},"displayHeaderFooter":false,"margin":{"top":"2cm","right":"2cm","bottom":"2cm","left":"2cm"},"format":"a4","printBackground":true}}'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /home/u1666881/public_html/royal_ambarrukmo/api/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: npm: command not found sh: node: command not found

this is the code i use

```
return Pdf::view('leave', ['data' =>$leave, 'dp' => $dp, 'eo' => $eo, 'al' => $al, 'staff' => $staff, 'id'=> $id, 'ids' => $ids, 'users' => $users, 'quota' => $quota]) ->format('a4') ->margins(2, 2, 2, 2, Unit::Centimeter)->name('leave-'.now()->format('Y-m-d').'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatie Laravel Pdf uses Browsershot and Puppeteer, Puppeteer is a node package. You will need Node +7.6 and Puppeteer installer on the server.

Assuming the server is Ubuntu. Install node.

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

Then install Puppeteer.

```
npm install puppeteer --location=global
```

This is also described in the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v4/requirements).

Comment: Based on the documentation also chaing permissions on chromium is maybe needed. sudo chmod -R o+rx /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium